# Can a PieChart from iOS-charts be drawn from a different starting angle than top dead center?

Tags: ios, ios-charts

A PieChart from the [iOS-charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) library is drawn starting from top dead center (90 degrees scientific) and clockwise for every next section of the pie. Is it possible to start at a different angle?

Also a user can rotate the chart on screen, how can that be disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1)

Check out the "`rotationAngle` property of your pieCharView.  The documentation for that property says:

```
/// current rotation angle of the pie chart
///
/// **default**: 270 --> top (NORTH)
/// - returns: will always return a normalized value, which will be between 0.0 < 360.0
```

So try resetting the angle programmatically via something like:

```
    self.pieChartView.rotationAngle = 180.0
```

2)

There's a `rotationEnabled` property on the chart that you can set to `false` to disable rotation.

Comment: Can't believe I missed those. Must have been the beer or the coffee... or both?